# htaccess url in xampp - Not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is how I'm going to your design and content on the website, so it must first develop on localhost first

I have looked at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVkR1FHBigk

it just has to be when I'm done I just like to throw it over to the service where I need to right it somewhere / customize it according to how my url is on the website;)

at present I write for example index.php so it will be / Cover / and not just the front /

For example if I write write on to the other side then I say index.php, but would like that it was / Cover /

For example, when I need to download a picture and I will do like this:

```
<img src="img/nyhederinto/hej.png">
```

They want to have like this

```
<img src="/img/nyhederinto/hej.png">
```

i have try its here:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php



RewriteRule ^forside/ index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Rewrite base for example if your folder is test in 
www directory add this code in your htacess.

```
RewriteBase /test/
```

Or make sure in your apache config file httpd.conf this line should not be commented

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: httpd.conf are not be commented, and its not working on : `RewriteBase /nyabsb/`